# If number have no value it should placed last(LINQ)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using linq to sql and my code looks like this:

```
 var agendaLists =
                        dataContext.view_Agendas.Where(m => m.MeetingID == meetingID)
                            .OrderBy(n => n.Number)
                            .ThenBy(n => n.CaseNumber)
                            .ThenByDescending(s => s.MainYN)
                            .ToList();
```

So basicly our "n.Number" is the order number. everything works fine its sorted 1,2,3,4 etc which is correct. but if a object have no value in n.Number it will be displayed in the top but I want it to be placed last.

Today it sorts like this, lets say we get 4 objects back:

```
Null, 1, 2, 3
```

I want it sorted like this:

```
1, 2, 3, Null
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this approach, presuming `Number` is an `int?`:

```
var agendaLists = dataContext.view_Agendas
    .Where(m => m.MeetingID == meetingID)
    .OrderBy(m => n.Number.HasValue ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(n => n.Number)
    .ThenBy(n => n.CaseNumber)
    .ThenByDescending(s => s.MainYN)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried "HasValue ? 0 : 1" but now it renders like this 2, 1 , null

Comment: @Obsivus: have you really tried `.OrderBy(m => n.Number.HasValue ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(n => n.Number)
    .ThenBy(n => n.CaseNumber)
    .ThenByDescending(s => s.MainYN)`? Because the first `OrderBy` just splits into two groups, the one with `NULL` and the one with values in `Number`.

Comment: My wrong let me test it again I missed the second thenby

Answer (score 4):

try the following:

```
n => n.Number ?? int.MaxValue
```

I dont remember if you actually have to check for `DBNull`, but it would be the same.

Comment: Personally i'm not a fan of replacement values because those could be valid values. `NULL` is not `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: True :)